# Matching object property which is an object within a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

For a string such as the following:

```
`const someConst= {
name: 'someName',
someProp: {
    somePropOfSomeProp: 'value'
}};`
```

How would i match the value of `someProp` ?

Assumptions:

- the property name is always known `someProp`
- the property value would always be of type object
- The `someProp` object cannot have nested objects. It will be flat.

I am using Javascript regex to solve this problem.

To provide more context to the type of structure we can expect for `someProp`. This is basically supposed to be the `bindings` property for angular components. So expected values could be the following:

```
bindings: {
someBinding: '=',
someOtherBinding: '@'
}
```

OR the props for `bindings` may not be on the same line. So they could be:

```
bindings: { someBinding: '=', someOtherBinding: '@' }
```

So basically i would need:

```
{
    someBinding: '=',
    someOtherBinding: '@'
}
```

Comment: Why write javascript as strings, and then parse them with regex

Comment: remove `const someConst= ` from the begining and then parse the string with `JSON.parse`

Comment: Can there be nested objects inside the `someProp` object? Is the data from a safe source? If both answers are "yes", I'd be inclined to use the JS engine to evaluate the data.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee: But that isn't valid JSON data, even without the `const` decl.

Comment: @adeneo I can imagine some uses, like some kind of script to act on some external code, for analysis or migration or data-mining.

Comment: @spanky ooh yeah, keys are not inside quotes. then, hopefully eval.. my goodness!!

Comment: I am writing a webpack loader to transform some js code before adding it to my bundle. This is the usecase. JS code is provided as string by webpack to loaders.

Comment: If you know exactly the structure of the someProp object, it *might* be possible with a regex, but if someProp can be *any* Object (with lots of nested things), it will become really hard or impossible to parse with a regex.

Comment: Updated question with the expected structure of someProp.

Comment: Regarding your edit, the regex should then be pretty simple overall, assuming there can never be a `}` anywhere within, except to close the object. However, if there's a property that has a string like `"foo {bar} baz"`, that will mess it up.

Comment: Is this on the server, like in NodeJS? If so, there are JS parsers available, which will let you parse it, traverse to the property you want, and serialize that subtree  back to JS code, without ever actually executing it.

Comment: @spanky this will not be the case. To provide even more context, my loader has to transform bindings for components in angular. Will edit again to include this context.

Comment: It is on the server using nodejs yes.

Comment: So then for a regex, try [`/someProp\s*:\s*(\{[^}]*\})/`](https://regex101.com/r/BS0MCF/1), otherwise I'd personally lean toward an actual JS parser.

Comment: @spanky that regex seems to work if the `someProp` object is multiline but returns null if it is not.

Comment: @asulaiman: It should work either way. The `\s*` and the `[^}]*` will both capture zero or more characters, irrespective if they're newlines. https://regex101.com/r/BS0MCF/2

Comment: Here it's updated to reflect your updated question: https://regex101.com/r/BS0MCF/3

Comment: @spanky much better. Only tweak i need now is to exclude `bindings:` because i only care about the value and not the key here.

Comment: @asulaiman: it's already excluded in the capture group. In the demo, look at the match information on the right side of the page. The new demos are the same as the original, just updated with the new `bindings` property name.

Comment: ...I guess you could change it to this if you prefer to not have the capture group. You get the separated value either way. [`/(?!bindings\s*:\s*)(?:\{[^}]*\})/`](https://regex101.com/r/BS0MCF/4)

Comment: @spanky yeah the issue was using `match` as opposed to `exec` now i get both matches. Thank you, you can post this as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Sounds good. I can't post a full answer right now, but will in a few hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152860/discussion-between-asulaiman-and-spanky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a regex to obtain the specific requirements in the question, you can use this:

```
/(?!bindings\s*:\s*)(?:\{[^}]*\})/
```

[Regex101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/BS0MCF/4)

It uses a negative lookahead on the property name and colon so that it isn't included in the result.

However, this regex assumes there can be no `}` character at all before the one that is used to terminate the object. So if somewhere in that object there's a string that includes a `}`, it will break.

In the extended discussion, you asked how to get the full object as well. This is more complicated, and is showing that using a JS parser like [Esprima](http://esprima.org) is very likely going to be a much better and more reliable solution.

Comment: Thanks i will check that parser out.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matched the whole object including the name someProp:

```
/someProp: {\n\s*somePropOfSomeProp\:.*\n}/g
```

Use parenthesis to have a capturing group that you can use to fine-tune what you want to use. For example :

```
/someProp: ({\n\s*somePropOfSomeProp\:.*\n})/g
```

---

Some caveat : may fail if value string contains also `somePropOfSomeProp:`, I haven't test enough cases. Or if value goes on several lines.

you can check at https://regex101.com/r/AE2dNJ/4

**Quick explanation :**

Find `someProp: {` followed by a newline, followed by spaces on the same line and then `somePropOfSomeProp:`, then everything following until newline, and then the closing bracket on the next line.

Comment: Thank you for answering but i am actually looking to match the entire someProp object. If you look at my updated question you will see what i expect at the end.